# How to retrieve session value stored in one aspx page to Generic Handler file

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an aspx page in which I stored textbox value in a session as `Session["uname"]=txtUserName.Text`. now i want to get that session value in ashx file. In ashx file I wrote `string str=context.Session["uname"].ToString()` bt it gives me nullReference error.Any other method to do this??

Comment: still gives the same error

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your handler (.ashx file) is implementing this interface:

```
System.Web.SessionState.IRequiresSessionState
```

If you only need read only access to session then use:

```
System.Web.SessionState.IReadOnlySessionState
```

They are both marker interfaces.

From MSDN on [IRequiresSessionState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.irequiressessionstate(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Specifies that the target HTTP handler requires read and write access to session-state values. This is a marker interface and has no methods.